# creating a custom column from joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I am terrible with sub queries if that is what i need to do. First let me show you a preview of my tables and what i'm trying to do.

[image]

this is the result i want at the end:

```
business.name
reviews_count (total count, matching the current queries business_id)
where the b.industry_id matches 7
```

This is what i'm trying but i feel stuck and dont know how to match the total count, let me explain:

```
select
b.name,
reviews_count as (select count(*) as count from reviews where business_id = b.business_id),
from business as b
left join reviews as r
on r.business_id = b.id
where b.industry_id = 7
```

the sub query business_id needs to match the the current businesses id that is being run. Hope i made sense. ( reviews_count doesnt exist, i just made it up to use when i output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    b.name,
    count(distinct r.id)
FROM
    businesses b
    JOIN reviews r ON r.business_id = b.id
WHERE b.industry_id = 7
GROUP BY b.id
```

That way you can avoid the subquery alltogether.

Comment: thanks, i never did like sub queries, they always confused me, group by didnt pass my mind lol. thanks :)

Comment: i added left join , join by itself wasnt showing the correct results